# Why Declaration of static variable with non-constant does not give Error in g++

Tags: c++, c

```
 int main ( )
 {
       int a = 1 ;
       static int b = a ;
 }
```

This piece of code gives error in **gcc 4.3.2** as

> error : initializer element is not constant.

But it runs fine on **g++ 4.3.2**.
 Someone Please Explain why this is not giving error in g++ 4.3.2.

Comment: The two versions you've posted are same

Comment: @Zaffy One's a C compiler, the other's a C++ compiler.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Different behavior,standards etc. :D

Comment: And +1 here too. Good question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it is valid in C++ (and not valid in C).

> (C++11, 6.7p4) "Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope
>               entity with static storage duration, if applicable, is performed before
>               its block is first entered. [...] Otherwise such a variable is
>               initialized the first time control passes through its declaration;
>               such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of
>               its initialization."

Comment: Does this mean that `static`s can be initialized at runtime in C++ or am I not understanding the specification correctly?

Comment: @user1294203: it means exactly that. And since non-constant initialization can have side effects (for class types) it's essential that the implementation does in fact do it at the correct time, at runtime.